# osx 10.7.5 terminal operation rmdir

Tags: macos, terminal, rmdir

I'm learning command line using osx terminal. I tried to remove an empty directory but it says Directory not empty. here's what I did:

```
$pwd
/desktop/temp/stuff/things/frank/joe/alex

$ls
$(shows nothing)

$cd ..

$pwd
/desktop/temp/stuff/things/frank/joe

$rmdir alex
rmdir: alex: Directory not empty
```

Can you help me with this? thank you

Comment: Delete folders recursive using -r. rm -rf folder

Answer (score 1):

Try `ls -a` instead of `ls` to show all files in the directory. There may be invisible files (starting with a `.`) in that directory.

Comment: You should delete the .DS_Store file with `rm .DS_Store` and then you should be able to remove the directory. You can also delete the while directory and all the contents with `rm -r alex`

Comment: i see. but this is weird, i only created those folders as an excercise, i've never modified any of them, any idea where the DS_Store come from?

Comment: It is a Mac OS file which stores information about the directory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store